# how to test "save" method of a service using Nunit test in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to test an service method which simply add an item to static list.

Code below throws no error but fails to test,

```
public class ToDoService : IToDoService
{
    private static List<ToDoItem> database = new List<ToDoItem>();

    public List<ToDoItem> GetAllTodos()
    {
        return database;
    }

    public void SaveTodo(string text)
    {
        database.Add(new ToDoItem { Text = text });
    }
```

UnitTest:

```
private Mock<IToDoService> todoService;
private List<ToDoItem> list = new List<ToDoItem>();

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    todoService = new Mock<IToDoService>();
}

    [Test]
    public void TestSave()
    {
        todoService.Setup(x => x.SaveTodo("new item"));
        todoService.Object.SaveTodo("new item");
        var data = todoService.Object.GetAllTodos(); //data is null
        Assert.IsTrue(data.Any(a => a.Text == "new item"));
    }
```

whats missing here?

Comment: "fails to test" what does this even mean?

Comment: @IanKemp, I have edited post, its still empty when adding an item in test method

Comment: You have created an empty list completely unrelated to the thing you are testing, added nothing to that list, and yet for some reason you expect it to contain an item you added elsewhere. The code is behaving exactly as it should.

Comment: Your `TodoService` is essentially a mock itself as it stores everything in a `List<>`. It doesn't need mocking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah but what if I want to use with mock, its for practice

Comment: Practice what? If you want to check how mocks work, you actually have to tell the mock what to return when you call `GetAllTodos()`. The mock doesn't store any data and wouldn't know what to do when you call `Add` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you created a Mock against your System Under Test(ToDoService).

SUT should be concrete and Mock all its dependencies.

```
var service = new TodoService();
service.SaveTodo("new item")
Assert.IsTrue(service.Database.Any(a => a.Text == "new item"));
```

Comment: I g ot your point and worked that way, but what if I want to use mock ? can you share it too?

Comment: You are using Mock(the tool) already and it's working fine. I guess the question is when to use Mocks? Mocks are used to examine interactions between SUT and its dependencies/collaborators... Let us say you have a dependency like IDbContext then you can mock your IDbContext to change the state of your SUT.

Answer (score 2):

You are not testing the `ToDoService` but the mocked version of `IToDoService`.

The only way you can test this is to call `GetAllTodos()` after you have added it.

try this

```cs
private IToDoService todoService;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    todoService = new ToDoService();
}

[Test]
public void TestSave()
{
    todoService.SaveTodo("new item");
    Assert.IsTrue(data.GetAllTodos().Any(x => x.Text == "new item");
}
```

Comment: I got your point but getallTodos still returns null by mocked service, how to make it work

Comment: @user5570680 updated it with an example.